What is the area of the octagonal table-tennis racquet?
During the Olympics tennis table events at Paris 2024, I discovered that any form of racquet is allowed, even octagonal ones.
You can see an image of such racquet below:

I wanted to know if the area of such racquet is the same of the area of "traditional" (lookalike-oval) racket we are used to. And if it is not the same, by how many centimeters square they differ in most cases?

Here is a comparison (scroll down a bit) of one traditional to octagonal racket. The octagonal in the image has an area that is about 1.5 square centimeters larger (236.04 vs 234.59), so about 0.6% larger.  This would seem to be the case as long as the oval and octagon share the same length and width.
However, since ITTF rules do not specify the size, there is not really a simple answer here. There is no set maximum "diameter" so I could easily play an oval that is larger than your octagon or vice versa.
It appears that one purported advantage of the octagon is that when held against the table, more of the hitting surface is close to the table (since the oval curves away smoothly, while the straight side does not).  At least this is what one company's marketing would claim.
